# Given complex series, the natural boundary is the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

How to prove that the series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} z^{n !}=z^{1!}+z^{2!}+z^{3!}+ \cdots $$
has the natural boundary $|z|=1$.

I did a similar problem to this where I was able to get an iterative functional relationship and show that all of them have singularities at $|z|=1.$ But I couldn't able to do it here. Any help in solving this is much appreciated.

Comment: The sum diverges at $e^{i2\pi r}$ whenever $r \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @achillehui thank you for the reply. Could you explain it a little bit more.

Comment: let's say $z = e^{i2\pi r}$ and $r = \frac{p}{q}$. when $2k+1 \ge q$, $q | (2k+1)! \implies z^{(2k+1)!} = 1$. This means aside from finitely many terms, the summands in the series are all $1$ and the series diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: @achillehui thank you for the explanation. Can't this be done using a functional relationship like $F(z^{1!}), F(z^{3!}), \cdots$ etc.

Comment: @achillehui That series diverges for every $z$ on the boundary. That doesn't prove much.

Comment: What you have on the left and right aren't the same. Are you powers supposed to be just odd factorials or all factorials?

Comment: @AlfredYerger thank you pointing that our. I've edited it. I still don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Can you tell me what you don't like about achille's suggestion? I think it's short, sweet and to the point.

Comment: @AlfredYerger, as I mentioned before I was looking for a iterative functional relationship approach. It's ok, I'll try to follow his argument. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the behavior of this function along the radius terminating at $e^{i2\pi q},$ where $q\in \mathbb Q.$